# What is the usage of V option in sort command

Tags: linux, sort

Having a command `ls -1 | grep war | sort -V | tail -n1` to sort and list a war file name likes **abc-1.4.3.12.war**.

What is the usage of V option with sort command?

Comment: Did you try with and without this option to compare results?

Answer (score 3):

https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html

> **‘-V’**
>   **‘--version-sort’**
>
> Sort by version name and number. It behaves like a standard sort, except that each sequence of decimal digits is treated numerically as an index/version number. (See [Details about version sort](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Details-about-version-sort.html#Details-about-version-sort).)

Example:

With standard sort:

```
$ printf '%s\n' abc-1.4.3.12.war abc-12.1.war abc-1.11.war | sort
abc-1.11.war
abc-12.1.war
abc-1.4.3.12.war
```

With version sort:

```
$ printf '%s\n' abc-1.4.3.12.war abc-12.1.war abc-1.11.war | sort -V
abc-1.4.3.12.war
abc-1.11.war
abc-12.1.war
```

**But you can also use the `-v` option in `ls`, there is no need to use `grep` and `sort` here**:

```
$ touch abc-1.4.3.12.war abc-12.1.war abc-1.11.war
$ ls -1 *war
abc-1.11.war
abc-12.1.war
abc-1.4.3.12.war
$ ls -1v *war
abc-1.4.3.12.war
abc-1.11.war
abc-12.1.war
```

Comment: answer is more clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

man sort says

> ```
>    -V, --version-sort
>           natural sort of (version) numbers within text
> ```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493205/unix-sort-of-version-numbers